# Reclaim Space on Google Cloud SQL?

Tags: google-cloud-sql

How do i reclaim space on a Google Cloud SQL DB?

== Extra Info ==

I have a DB on Google Cloud SQL which is showing as using 2.5GB, but it's show's as less than 100MB in my DB client and only show as 17MB when I take a backup.

I noticed the size had crept up as I was saving lots of data into one field, but have since cleared this data. I expected the space to be reclaimed but that has not happened weeks later.

I did not have binary logs turned on either so cannot reclaim that space.

The [docs state](https://cloud.google.com/sql/faq#managing-your-instances) that the instances running on MySQL 5.5 require the `innodb_file_per_table` flag to be set on, but I have set this on and I'm running v5.6.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimize-table.html And technically off-topic. This isn't a programming issue, it's more a DBA-type thing.

Comment: Sorry. I had followed the support route suggested by Google in it's help documentation. I tried what you said but I could not recover any of the space. I may just try a backup-wipe-restore to see if that helps.